# (C#-ASP.NET-REDIRECT-LOGIN) how to get the url before redirecting the page? In login method

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect, authentication

how to get the url before redirecting the page?

Example: in A.aspx page has a link that redirects to page b.aspx, and that in "pageload" on page b.aspx I need to grab the link from the previous page: A.aspx.

The scenario is:

When the timeout expires I need to redirect the user to the login page again, but I need  save the url that it was accessing, because when he login again I need redirect it to the same page

(C#-ASP.NET-REDIRECT-LOGIN) how to get the url before redirecting the page? In login method

Ty.

Edit

```
***if (Page.Request.RawUrl != null && !Page.Request.RawUrl.ToUpper().Equals("/DEFAULT.ASPX"))
   {
     cookie.Value = Page.Request.RawUrl.ToString();
     cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(SessionLengthMinutes * 2);
     Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
   }***
```

I use this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the link in a session object and then redirect the user.
On successful login retreive the value form session object.

Session["PathBeingAccessed"] = "www.xyz.com";

```
if (Page.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            {
           Response.Redirect(Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(),false);
            }
```

On Login:

```
if(Session["PathBeingAccessed"]!=null)
{
Response.Redirect(Session["PathBeingAccessed"].toString();)
}
```

Comment: thanks Vahi, I tried using this method but it didn't work. The page on which it is called it has the null value.

Answer (score 0):

Be carrefull it's a big security issue if the UrlReferrer is not on same web site; I think you need to check url before (domain or whaterver else)